# UI Grid header taking up entire page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

So, I've been beating my head against the wall on a problem where angular-ui-grid's header is taking up the entire height of the screen.

I've reduced the issue down to one file in one plunk. http://plnkr.co/edit/XR7OVXjwSodqTNRBAVnv?p=preview

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Broken ui-grid</title>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="///ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('sample', ['ui.grid']);
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.0.7/ui-grid.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        angular.module('sample').controller('SampleController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
            $scope.uiGridOptions = {
                rowHeight: 36,

                data: [
                    { date: Date.now() / 1000, blah1: "Test data"}
                ]
            };

            $scope.uiGridOptions.columnDefs = [
                { field: "blah1", displayName: "blah", width: 150 }
            ];
        }]);
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.0.7/ui-grid.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body ng-app="sample" ng-controller="SampleController">
    <div id="dailyGrid" ui-grid="uiGridOptions"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after about an hour of searching and fiddling, I've found the problem.

All I needed to do to fix the problem was add a `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the document, and boom! problem solved!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
... code snip ...
```

Plunkr with fix: http://plnkr.co/edit/6rRIcjaL1yPF6GKRTkUT?p=preview

I suspect that the browser (Google Chrome) was rendering in some non-html5 mode without the doctype. I didn't realize that there would be a difference between doctype and no doctype.

Hopefully this is useful to someone else as well.